# ClassLoader issue on WAS 7.0.0.0 - DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

Tags: java, websphere, classloader, classcastexception, apache-cocoon

I am working with a Web application written in cocoon framework (Java) and running on WAS 7.0.0.0. 
When running on WAS 6.X.X.X everything works fine.

However, on WAS 7 during runtime I am receiving the following error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance`

We suspect that this is a ClassLoader issue.

I have tried many steps to overcome this issue:

1. I have tried to add in the WAS Administration Console a new Custom properties:

   Application servers -> Server Name -> Process definition -> Java Virtual Machine -> Custom properties

   - Name = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
   - Value = org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

   But this did not resolve the problem!
2. I tried to change the WAS class loader order in the WAS Admin Console between parent first and parent last - both options did not resolve the issue.

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Because was7 must have these jars inbuilt. You need to remove these jars from your ear/war and then deploy. Multiple copies of the same jars are conflicting.

Regards,